# Shell script doesn't work when I export a variable inside it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a script called `installscript` which needs a change to the PATH variable.

`BuildScript` file has the following code:

```
export PATH+=:foo/bar/
./installscript
```

Running `./BuildScript` or `source BuildScript` fails with an error in `installscript`

I have made a `NewScript` and call `BuildScript` from it after exporting the PATH variable

```
export PATH+=:foo/bar/
./BuildScript.sh
```

running source `NewScript` works.

I don't understand why running `BuildScript` alone won't work.

Comment: "*fails with an error*" --> What error?

Comment: Use `set -x` to see what is happening.

Comment: @techraf .. It fails with a compile error in as. Says as can't find libopcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's likely because you should not use relative directory paths in a `PATH`. A relative path is a pathname that doesn't start with a slash. Try

```
PATH+=:/path/to/foo/bar    # Use absolute path starting with /
```

instead and don't call scripts with `./script.sh` but `script.sh` and let the system find the programs along the `PATH`.

Also note that executing a script cannot change the environment of the parent. If you need that, scripts must be *sourced* with `. /path/to/script` or `source /path/to/script`.

Comment: @ceving When BuildScript has a `cd some_other_dir` and needs to find foo/bar relative to the org dir it will. And when foo is a subdir of where BuildScript is, adding foo/bar/ will only work when your current dir is the BuildScript dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/foo/bar
. BuildScript.sh

# or

cd /path/to/foo/bar
. ./BuildScript.sh
```